# Waiting for response from the server to continue the program

Tags: reactjs

For my bioinformatics work, I want to build a React app, connected to Node.js server (Express).

The idea is that the client picks the samples they need to analyse, and the server would process the workflow. I want the program to execute process one on each sample, after that process two on each sample.

It's very import to wait for the process to end (and get a positive response from the server) before running the following process. I thought a nested loop would work, but no.

```
processes.forEach(p => {
    samples.forEach(s => {
       runProcess()
  })
})
```

I tried the async/await method, but without success.

Comment: Why is it up to the client to orchestrate that? Why not send the samples, and let the _server_ run the appropriate processes?

Comment: Because I would like to add a progress bar, and update it when a sample analysis process ended. Sorry, I am a beginner and I don't really know if I can get responses from the server when a process is still running

Comment: You can respond 202 Accepted and provide a status endpoint the client can poll, see e.g. https://farazdagi.com/posts/2014-10-16-rest-long-running-jobs/

Comment: Sound great! I will work on it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: So I send a array with all my samples I want to analyse to the server. I would like to process each sample, and go the the next sample. Do I need to use a loop fro that?

Answer (score 1):

forEach does not support asynchronous, for loop can support asynchronous calls. you can try like this.

```js
    const wait = (time) => new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, time)
    });

    async function runCode() {
      const arr = [1,2,3,4]
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // start your request 
        await wait(3000)
       // request finished then next will start
        console.log('item', i);
      }
    }

    runCode()
```